# How to get Java to see OracleSQL sequences contained in a separate schema file using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, schema

I have a schema.sql file that contains a database, including a sequence I created to increment the primary keys

```
    CREATE SEQUENCE seq_1
    MINVALUE 1
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    CACHE 10;
```

My program runs in a separate Java file that connects to the database schema correctly but the java program can not find the sequence

```
    String query = "INSERT INTO users"
    + "(userID) VALUES"
    + "(?)";
    PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement (query);
    stat.setInt(1, seq_1.NEXTVAL);
```

Returns

```
    error: cannot find symbol
    statement.setInt(1, seq_1.NEXTVAL);
                        ^
```

Is there any way to keep the sequences in the schema file or do they have to be in the java file?

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, the same error is thrown

Comment: you can't pass a sequence name or nextval through a prepared statement. And you don't need to: `insert into users (userid) values (seq_1.nextval)`